# How to get a the scrollbar to move down to the parent element I choose

Tags: html, css

I have a table inside a div that is inside of a div. Like the snippet below:

```css
*
{
  overflow: hidden;
}

.body
{
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.header
{
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
}

.page
{
  height: 198px;
  width: 298px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container
{
}

.table
{
  height: 96px;
  width: 396px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="header">
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="table">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here I want want the `"page"` element to be where the scrollbars are located for whenever scrollbars are needed. That's why everything is set to `overflow: hidden;` except the `"page"` element. Now this doesn't work on width overflow and  is clipped - note that all height overflow work as intended thought and gives a scrollbar on the correct `"page"` element.

It is also useless to set `overflow: auto;` to the `"container"` element as the scrollbar is on that element and not the parent `"page"` element.

How can I get an overflow inside the child element to move down to the parent element I choose so I always get the scrollbar where I want it?

Comment: Try setting the overflow property on the page class to overflow:scroll instead of auto.

Comment: @FrederickM.Rogers That will just show the scrollbars all the time (what I don't want) and also not give them the actual functionality I need - meaning they are visible, but do not work.

Comment: Have a look at @Callum 's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, then the reason the scroll wasn't working is because of `overflow:hidden`, that property means everything outside of the elements width will be completely hidden so it can't be scrolled to.

The solution is to set `overflow:visible` to everything other then the `page` element, this means everything that overflows will still be visible, but the elements with this property won't have their own scroll bars.

Here is your edited snippet I think it achieves what you wanted, hope it helps:

```css
.body
{
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.header
{
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
}

.page
{
  height: 198px;
  width: 298px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container
{
}

.table
{
  height: 96px;
  width: 396px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="header">
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="table">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that helped. Though I need some other element to be hidden that's why I did * { overflow: hidden }, but I modified your answer to be .page * { overflow: visible } so it only applies to the children of .page.